# Почему возникает проблема с передачей данных через глобальную переменную js?

Tags: javascript, html

Почему возникает проблема с передачей данных  через глобальную переменную js?
Когда перехожу на страницу, где использую значение переменной(second.html), возникает такая ошибка:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'globalVar' of undefined

fi.js

```
function sent(){
    window.storage = {}; 
    window.storage.globalVar = document.getElementById('input').value;
}
```

se.js

```
var d = document;
var name = window.storage.globalVar;
function addRow()
{
    var tbody = d.getElementById('table').getElementsByTagName('TBODY')[0];
    var row = d.createElement("TR");
    tbody.appendChild(row);
    var td1 = d.createElement("TD");
    row.appendChild(td1);
    td1.innerHTML = name;
}
```

first.html

```
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="se.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="" method="post" onsubmit="sent();">
    <input type="text" id="input">
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

second.html

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="fi.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="addRow();return false;">
  <table id="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Some</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: прежде чем `globalVar` станет глобальной (и вообще будет объявлена) нужно выполнить `sent()`

Comment: У меня в sent() как раз и должна появляться эта глобальная переменная. Те мне надо оставить пустой sent(), а только после него написать присвоение? @MishaSaidov

Comment: Немного не понял. В какой последовательности выполняются эти 2 скрипта?

Comment: Сперва в fi.js мы получаем значение из input и записываем в переменную. Затем в se.js мы с этими данными работаем. @MishaSaidov

Comment: В любом случае `sent()` должен выполниться раньше, чем `var name = window.storage.globalVar`. Если  `sent()` выполняется раньше, чем `addRow()`, то возможно решением для вас будет поместить эти 2 строки `var d = document; var name = window.storage.globalVar;` в addRow() (и выполнять `addRow()` после `sent()` еще раз повторюсь)

Comment: Соглашусь, но у меня sent() никак не может выполниться после addRow() тк он происходит по нажатию кнопки. Я сейчас добавлю html код @MishaSaidov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И так, в первую очередь, js переменные, объявленные на одной странице не будут доступны на другой, какими бы глобальными они не были. Передать переменную с одной страницы на другую можно по разному, например через `cookie`, `localStorage`, `get-запрос` и др. Так как у вас имеется форма, лучше посмотрите в сторону `get-запросов`.

Во вторых, старайтесь навешивать события на элементы из js. У такого варианта есть несколько преимуществ, а главное вы не теряете контроль над порядком выполнения всего этого (ну и можете несколько событий навешать сразу).

На основе всего вышесказанного ваш код должен выглядеть примерно так (я не буду расписывать все за вас, но путь укажу):

```
function sent(e) {
    //типа так
    localStorage.setItem('globalVar', document.getElementById('input').value);
    //или так
    document.cookie = "globalVar=" + document.getElementById('input').value;
    //или так
    //немного костыльно, и можно обойтись без js даже, указав action="second.html"
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = "/second.html" + "?" + "globalVar=" + document.getElementById('input').value;
}
```

Теперь это надо прочитать

```
function addRow() {
    //читаем из ls
    var name = localStorage.globalVar;
    //читаем из куки (лучше найти в интернете библиотек для работы с кукисами
    var name = document.cookie.replace(/globalVar=/g, ""); //так лучше не делать
    //читаем из get
    var name = window.location.search.replace('?', '').replace(/globalVar=/g, "");


    //ну и т.д.
    var d = document;
    var tbody = d.getElementById('table').getElementsByTagName('TBODY')[0];
    var row = d.createElement("TR");
    tbody.appendChild(row);
    var td1 = d.createElement("TD");
    row.appendChild(td1);
    td1.innerHTML = name;
}
```

То, что я написал нуждается в серьезной доработке. Это всего лишь подсказки, чтобы понимать как вообще данная проблема решается.